# Oauth2.0 web server authentication flow using python

Tags: authentication

I have seen several python implementations of oauth2.0 username-password flow to authenticate to salesforce. There are also several python libraries which offer this flow.

But is there a python implementation of web server authentication flow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it out at this blog:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/01/python-and-the-force-com-rest-api-simple-simple-salesforce-example.html

Hope this helps others with same doubt

Thanks